# Javascript-PHP - assing a concatenated string to a variable

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I want to include a variable between two strings and assign this to a new variable. I tried

```
 var row="<tr><td>".$i."</td></tr>";
```

and

```
   var row="<tr><td>"$i"</td></tr>";
```

and

```
var row="<tr><td>$i</td></tr>";
```

and

```
var row=$("<tr><td>$i</td></tr>");
```

and

```
var row=$("<tr><td>"$i"</td></tr>");
```

and

```
var row=$("<tr><td>".$i."</td></tr>");
```

but none of the previous works.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Is it javascript or php ?

Comment: You're mixin JS and PHP. `$row="<tr><td>$i</td></tr>";`

Comment: Its javascript including php-html tags.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis - Check below answers it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing js & php.

**PHP:**

```
$row = "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td></tr>";
```

Or

```
$row = "<tr><td>$i</td></tr>";
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var row = "<tr><td>" + i + "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
$row = '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
```

in PHP use `$` sign instead of `var` for declaring variables

If you want to echo a PHP variable in JavaScript var string do:

```
var row = '<tr><td><?php echo $i ?></td></tr>'
```